# How to make a web page button that invokes MetaMask to mint an NFT to Ethereum mainnet?

Tags: web3js, contract-design, contract-deployment, contract-invocation, erc-721

What programming languages background is required to publish a web page that has a button on it, which when pressed, invokes MetaMask for the user to publish an ERC-721 token to Ethereum mainnet?

Nevermind the input fields of upload image and set metadata, just more curious about the HTML or Javascript code that goes into making that button that 1) calls in MetaMask to create a transaction, then 2) deploys the NFT to mainnet when the transaction completes. Example script would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that but the one I've found the easyest is using a js library called useDapp. Patrick Collins python video has a section of how to use the library, and you can go from there. You can find a mint page with a single mint button using react [here](https://github.com/FranciscoBuru/Auctions-Front/blob/master/src/components/FreeMint.jsx). Hope it helps.

Comment: thansk for the code in the link